# How to take image Attribute from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in Jquery I have take two div I want to take attribute **src** value

how can I achive this

thanks in advance

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

var a = document.getElementById("month1").src();
var b = document.getElementById("month2").src();
```

alert(a); alert(b)

```
<body>


<div id="month1"><img src="img/offer.png"></div>
<div id="month2"><img src="img/offer.png"></div>
<div id="month3">1111</div>
<div id="month4">222222</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var a = $('#month1').find('img').attr('src');
            var b = $('#month2').find('img').attr('src');
           alert(a);
alert(b);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the element by Id of div and find it descendant by using `.find()` method and dont forget to wrap inside document ready like so:

```
$(function(){
   var a = $("#month1").find('img').attr('src');
   var b = $("#month2").find('img').attr('src');

  alert(a); 
  alert(b)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's `attr()` function ([documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)).

Example:

```
var a = $("#month1 img").eq(0).attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var imgSrc1 = $('#month1').find('img').attr("src");
   var imgSrc2 = $('#month2').find('img').attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your code in [**ready()**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to make it run when DOM is finished loading
2. Use jQuery [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get the element attribute value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $('#month1 img').attr('src');
  var b = $('#month2 img').attr('src');

  $(document.body).append('<hr />' + a + '<br>' + b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="month1">
  <img src="img/offer.png">
</div>
<div id="month2">
  <img src="img/offer.png">
</div>
<div id="month3">1111</div>
<div id="month4">222222</div>
```

By using Pure Javascript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var a = document.getElementById('month1').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
  document.write(a);
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="month1">
  <img src="img/offer.png">
</div>
<div id="month2">
  <img src="img/offer.png">
</div>
<div id="month3">1111</div>
<div id="month4">222222</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is best way, imho.

```js
var one =  $('#month1 img').attr('src');
alert( one );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="month1"><img src="img/offer.png"></div>
<div id="month2"><img src="img/offer.png"></div>
<div id="month3">1111</div>
<div id="month4">222222</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give an id to the image tag

```
<body>
<div id="month1"><img id="image1" src="img/offer.png"></div>
<div id="month2"><img id="image2" src="img/offer.png"></div>
<div id="month3">1111</div>
<div id="month4">222222</div>

</body>
</html>
```

then you can directly access those value using these ids

```
var $img = $("#image1");
var src = $img.attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use following jquery to find all elements having tag name as 'img'.

```
    $( "img" ).each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Other clean way to find all tags having type image in input tag is given in jquery API. 
[image selector jquery](http://api.jquery.com/image-selector/)